# Barcode gnerator in a pdf document

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, pdf, barcode

I am using ASP.NET and I want to create a barcode in a pdf document by means of a third party component. Then I want to send this pdf document as an attachment.

Do you have any ideas how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this in the past. I used a few components.

1. Barcode generation (http://www.idautomation.com/servercontrols/)
2. PDF Generation (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)
3. Regular email class in .NET (System.Net.Mail)

A few notes:

1. The barcode generation results in an image, so the import to any PDF library will be able to handle it.
2. iTextSharp's documentation is lacking, in my opinion. It is a port of the Javas equivalent, so most things can be converted fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

Why not install ghostscript on the server and use this to generate the barcode from ps to pdf?

Link [here](http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the following solution using Aspose products:

1. [Create Barcode](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/default.aspx) using Aspose.Barcode for .NET
2. Create PDF or [add barcode image in the PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) using Aspose.Pdf for .NET
3. [Send the PDF as an email attachment](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.network-for-.net/sending-email-messages-with-smtp.html)

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.